# How to prepare wet basement wall for Drylok

Tags: walls, basement

I’m getting water in basement after rain and condensation remains on walls.  How do I prepare for drylok and which drylok is best?

Comment: First, make sure that the ground surface outside the house slopes away from the building in all directions. If it doesn't, correct that. https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/170066/18078

Comment: First you find and fix the source of the water leak.

Comment: Before spending a bunch are you doing an internal or external seal and what type of wall poured or block? Is there any paint on the walls now. Dry lock makes lots of promises but following the mfg instructions are absolutely necessary.